# Jquery DatePicker changing month using dropdown causing window scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, datepicker, drop-down-menu

I can only see my datepicker when i scroll the page.After scrolling if i click on datepicker , it opens as expected but after changing month using dropdown, the scroll position of window is moved up little bit causing datepciker hidden. So can't click on it.

Comment: Post some code, people will be able to help better.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the date picker event, 'beforeShow' to run a script to scroll the page to the optimal position.

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   beforeShow: function(input, inst) { ... }
});
```

The jQuery plugin [SCROLLTO](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) can help with that.  From its page:

> With this plugin, you will easily scroll overflowed elements, and the screen itself.
>   It gives you access to many different options to customize and various ways to specify where to scroll.

Again, you would be doing this with the function you specify in the beforeShow option.